# implicit param and overloading gotcha

Tags: scala, overloading, implicit

```
trait DAOContract[T <: Entity] {
  // default create
  def create(t: T): Option[Int]
}

trait UserContract extends DAOContract[User] {
  // provide alternate create method for transactional blocks
  def create(u: User)(implicit ss: Session): Either[String, Int]
  ...
}

// DAO provides create implementation with embedded session
class UserDAO(implicit val db: Connection) 
  extends DAO[User] with UserContract {

  import db.Driver.Implicit._
  import org.scalaquery.ql._
  ...
}
```

in a controller

```
dao.create(model) // boom, no implicit session
```

I hope I am missing something here: why is the scala compiler unable to differentiate between the 2 create method signatures above?

Basically makes it impossible for me to overload DAO operations without coming up with a different method naming convention for operations that are transactional (i.e. return Either) or standalone.

Or, I'm just going about things in the wrong way, entirely possible...

Comment: Could you please provide a self-contained piece of code that we could compile and work with?

Comment: not directly with all the plumbing, but try this code snippet, captures the problem: "http://pastebin.com/KvWA1hDv" Appears that implicit param enabled methods require a different signature; in other words, afaik, overloading not possible, would be nice to hear otherwise/see a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are reasons why Scala prohibits that:

1. Imagine that your `create` methods would be:

   ```
   def create(t: User): Function[Int,Something]
   def create(u: User)(implicit ss: Session): Either[String, Int]
   ```

   Then calling `create(x)(y)` would be applicable to both of them.
2. Even though the problem in (1.) could be perhaps resolved by if Scala compiler carefully examined of the types of the functions, **it'd be very error prone**. In such setup it would be very easy for programmers to make mistakes. Forcing different names for the functions ensures that programmers always know what they call.

---

If change your methods to have the same return type and if you're willing to take the risky way, you could try something like this:

```
trait Broken {
  final def foo(x: Int)(implicit session: String = null): Option[Int] =
    if (session == null) foo1(x)
    else foo2(x, session);

  def foo1(x: Int): Option[Int]
  def foo2(x: Int, session: String): Option[Int]
}
class Example extends Broken {
  def foo2(x: Int, y: String) = Some(2)
  def foo1(x: Int) = Some(1)
}

object Test extends App {
  def withImplicit(e: Example) = {
    implicit val imp = "hey"
    e.foo(1) // (imp)
  }
  def withoutImplicit(e: Example) = e.foo(1)

  println(withImplicit(new Example()));
  println(withoutImplicit(new Example()));
}
```

When an implicit value is available, the corresponding method is called. Otherwise, the method without the "session" argument is called. But I *strongly* discourage this approach. Just a slight mistake will lead to calling the wrong variant and this will be very hard to debug.

Comment: +1, nice explanation, Petr. For now I took the safe approach and renamed default DAO methods to createOne, updateOne, and deleteOne (although your workaround is tempting, given that I can do what I want, preserve the DAO namespace). Most persistence operations occur in transactional blocks, so create, update, delete with implicit session param are reserved for rollback-able operations where session is passed in to the transactional block implicitly "db.withSession { implicit ss: Session => ss.withTransaction{ for{//DAO calls here } }}"

Answer (score 0):

Your create methods have different sigs. One returns an Either, and the other one returns an Option. Plus the implicit. You probably need to use implicitly and return an Option[Int] from both

Comment: I need Either for for{...} transactional blocks that thread through right projections